# Temporary changes to /etc/passwd or /etc/group - how-to

Tags: linux, user-management, groups, passwd

I want to temporarily modify `/etc/passwd` and/or `/etc/group` to "remove" a user/group without deleting the line.

Is there a way to do that?

http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?threadId=1161913 seems to indicate it may not be supported (but may also be HPUX-specific).

Comment: Fully delete, or is it enough to disable?

Comment: @andol - I want to 'delete' using something like a comment perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From everything I have tried, there seems to be no way of doing what I am describing, so I'm going to mark this answer as the accepted one.

The only way to 'temporarily' disable a group is to `cp /etc/groups <path/to/backup>`, make the change in `/etc/groups`, and revert the change later if/when needed.

Answer (score 3):

to temporarily lock a user's account you can do `passwd -l username` which simply adds a '!' to the beginning of the password hash in `/etc/shadow`, preserving the user's password, and preventing them from being able to log in with any password.

Comment: is there an analog for `/etc/group`?

Comment: you can use `addgroup user group` and `delgroup user group`

Comment: I don't want to delete the group permanently, nor make all the changes to group memberships post-re-enabling

Comment: why does it matter which groups they belong to, while their account is locked? there is not an option for 'locking' a user from a group, there's no data to retain, so it's just a matter of removing them from the group or adding them to the group. or leaving them be, because without being able to log in, it doesn't matter what their group membership is.

Comment: @cpbills - I'm looking for a way to temporarily disable a group as well, and doing a full delete would remove all the memberships, requiring them to be recreated when the group is re-enabled (or, in this case, recreated), would it not?

Comment: `delgroup username groupname` simply removes a user from the group. it does not delete the group or remove other users from the group.

Comment: @cpbills - I need the group to be missing temporarily, though :-\

Comment: well, you could temporarily change the group's gid...

that would prevent members of the group from accessing files owned by that gid...

Answer (score 2):

If you are just disabling the account you could change their shell to /sbin/nologin.  For example, in /etc/passwd:

```
username:x:500:500:Firstname Lastname:/home/username:/sbin/nologin
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of `/etc/passwd`

```
cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.bak
```

Delete the user from the original, the backup will still have the user.

Make a script that deletes /etc/passwd and renames /etc/passwd.bak to /etc/passwd.

Set up the script in cron to do it automatically whenever you want it to run.

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing. I'm looking for a way of doing this *without* backing-up the file and making a destructive change